# Get directory path in PhpStorm Live Template

Tags: phpstorm

I'm trying to generate a namespace through PhpStorm's templating system (File and Code Templates), I can't see any helpers / means of getting this through PhpStorm's documentation.

I was wondering if there was a way to automatically define the namespace based on the directory:

```
<?php
// I'm wanting to apply to $namespace
namespace $namespace;

class ${NAME} implements
    \Zend\Mail\Mailable
{
    /** \Zend\Mail\Factory */
    private $factory;
...

}#set( $factory = "factory" ) #set( $this- = "this-" ) #set( $directory = ?)
```

If my directory/filename is `zend/mail/model/notice/send.php` I'd like this to generate a namespace of `Zend\Mail\Model\Notice;` I can get the class name through the `${NAME}` variable.

I'm aware I can have the template request the namespace through a dialog when the file is being created, however I was wondering if it's possible to automate this?

Comment: does this `namespace ${NAMESPACE};` not work?

Comment: It does - however it asks me to manually enter a namespace on the create dialog, I was thinking I could replace the path directory by replacing / with \ and replacing the first letter of each directory with an uppercase character.

Comment: So if you create a normal class does it ask you then?

Comment: No, it wouldn't ask me for a namespace unless I specify that a namespace should be present. I can generate a namespace from the file directory the file I'm adding is being added to, however I don't know how to get that directory using template variables. @AdamForbis

Answer (score 6):

if you want , you can use groovyScript.

for example, you can create a variable $FOLDER_OF_FILE$ and set this groovyScript to take the folder of file.

```
groovyScript("String[] p=_editor.getVirtualFile().getPath().split('/');String prevLast = p[p.length-2];")
```

you can change and adapt my example for your needs

Answer (score 2):

There are no predefined variables for file path, please vote for [IDEA-136387](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136387) to be notified on any progress with this feature.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-21711 is a bit more appropriate based on context, I guess. But it's for File Templates (which is what OP uses anyway).

Answer (score 1):

I've create a live template for magento modules and wanted to generate the namespace according to the file path of the php file. This works for me:

***Live template:***

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace $NAMESPACE$;

class $CLASSNAME$
{
    
}
```

***variable CLASSNAME***

```
fileNameWithoutExtension()
```

***variable NAMESPACE***

```
regularExpression(regularExpression(regularExpression(fileRelativePath(),"src/app/code/",""),"/\\w+\.php",""),"/",escapeString("\\"))
```

I use 3 replacements with regularExpression()

1. cut away "src/app/code"
2. cut away file name and trailing "/"
3. finally replace "/" with "" - it took me a while to figure out a working syntax to insert a "" ...